# R how to specify custom color gradients with breakpoints

Tags: r, ggplot2, usmap

I'm trying to create a custom gradient scale in R that will change colors based on values.

Basically:

I want the fill color to be a gradient between `darkblue` and `blue` for values that are between `1` and `50`.

I want the fill color to be a gradient between `lightblue` and `yellow` for values that are between `50` and `100`.

And so on...

I've tried the code below, but this is clearly the wrong way to do it:

```
scale_fill_gradientn(limits = c(0,50),colours=c("darkblue","blue"),na.value="#101010") +
scale_fill_gradientn(limits = c(50,100),colours=c("lightblue","yellow"),na.value="#101010") +
scale_fill_gradientn(limits = c(100,1000),colours=c("orange","orangered"),na.value="#101010") +
scale_fill_gradientn(limits = c(1000,10000),colours=c("darkred","red"),na.value="#101010") + 
scale_fill_gradientn(limits = c(10000,30000),colours=c("red","#FF877D"),na.value="#101010") +
```

Could someone help me out?

Edit:

Using this code:

```
scale_fill_gradientn(
  limits  = range(0,max(da$val)),
  colours = colours[c(1, seq_along(colours), length(colours))],
  values  = c(0, scales::rescale(colour_breaks, from = range(0,da$val)),range(0,da$val))) +
```

I get this effect:

[image: Example]

Which is close to what I'm going for, but I don't really understand the rescale code and what it's doing.

I want it to start as blue and go up to red using the breaks.

It's close - just starting at yellow.

**Edit:**

With help from @teunbrand, I got it it working!

Here's the code:

```
my_limits <- range(c(0, usa.dat[,50:ncol(usa.dat)]))
max_value <- max(usa.dat[, 50:ncol(usa.dat)])

for (i in 2:ncol(usa.dat)) {
  da <- data.frame(fips=usa.dat$countyFIPS,val=usa.dat[,i])
  tot <- sum(da$val)
  colour_breaks <- c(0,1,100,500,1000,10000,30000)
  colours <- c("#101010","blue","lightblue","yellow","red","darkred","magenta")
  
  current_max <- max(da$val)
  relative_max <- max_value / current_max
  
  theDate <- substr(names(usa.dat)[i],2,100)
  plot_usmap(regions = "counties",
             data=da,
             values="val"
  ) + 
  labs(title=paste("Covid-19 Deaths - ",str_replace_all(theDate,"\\.","/")," - Total: ",tot,sep='')) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(limits  = range(0, current_max),
                       colours = colours,
                       values = scales::rescale(colour_breaks, to = c(0, relative_max), from = c(0, max_value)),
                       name="Deaths",na.value="#101010") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(color = "#101010", fill = "#101010"))
  ggsave(paste(sprintf("%03d",i),".png",sep=''))
```

Results: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZcnhUr6ghw

Edit: Magma Palette: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrgYIl_xqUU

Edit 2: 3D version: https://youtu.be/Lk7E8o6VIQY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the exact points where a particular colour should be by using the `values` argument of the scale. In the example below, we want `"darkblue"` at 10, `"lightblue"` at 20 and `"yellow"` at 30.

The only catch is that the `values` argument works for rescaled values between 0 and 1, so we ought to fix the limits and apply the same rescaling to our breaks.

Lastly, because now values outside the 10-30 range are undefined, it might be best to repeat the colours at the extremes at the (rescaled) values 0 and 1.

```r
library(ggplot2)

colour_breaks <- c(10, 20, 30)
colours <- c("darkblue", "lightblue", "yellow")

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(
    limits  = range(mpg$cty),
    colours = colours[c(1, seq_along(colours), length(colours))],
    values  = c(0, scales::rescale(colour_breaks, from = range(mpg$cty)), 1),
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

As a small note: in your description it is unclear what the colour should be at 50: in one gradient it should be blue and in the other it should be lightblue. At best, you can set one of the colours (let's say blue) to 50 and use a 50 + a miniscule offset (e.g. `.Machine$double.eps`) for the lightblue break.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I'm trying to figure out how to pass the values from my dataset into the color scale thing.

Comment: My issue is that I'm using a bunch of plots to create an animation and I don't want the gradient scale to arbitrarily shift up. I want the colors to remain the same no matter how high the scale goes.

Comment: Fixing the limits (instead of having ggplot2 determine them dynamically) should be appropriate for that too.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to fix the limits. Do I use breaks as well?

Comment: If I just set the limit at max then you can barely see the color changes from the gradient it seems.

Comment: My goal is to make the colors pop even for low values in those areas despite the range going up to `30,000`

Comment: You can set them manually as well, and then use the manual limits in both the `limits` argument and in the `rescale(..., from = limits)` bit.

Comment: I almost need the gradient scale to introduce more and more colors as the limits go up, but not introduce the entire scale from the beginning.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: `scale_fill_gradientn(limits  = range(0,max(da$val)),
                         colours = colours[c(1, seq_along(colours), length(colours))],
                         values  = c(0, scales::rescale(colour_breaks, from = range(0,da$val)), 1))`

Comment: I get some interesting effects by changing the rescale `1` to something else - almost looks like kind of what i'm going for, except the colors are all backwards

Comment: I've lost the thread on what you exactly are trying to achieve. If you provide a self contained minimal example of the problem you're encountering, people could try to investigate where the problem occurs.

Comment: See my edit - I have added the code example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238105/discussion-between-user1274820-and-teunbrand).